# Regular functions which coincide in a neighbourhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

This is from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

[image]

It's not clear to me how he concludes that $S:=\{a\in X\mid f(a)=g(a)\}$ is dense in $X$.

Regardless of that, considering $S$ closed, it seems to me that density is irrelevant: notice that $X=(X\setminus U)\cup S$ and, because $X$ is irreducible, we get $S=X$. Right?

Comment: *If $Y$ is a topological space, $A$ is a dense subset of $Y$, and $A\subseteq B$, then $B$ is also dense.* In this case, $S$ is dense because it contains a non-empty open subset and the space is irreducible. But since $S$ is also closed, it must be equal to $X$. I did not understand your argument. Why $U=X$?

Comment: @Krish, you're right about $U=X$. I should have said "$X\setminus U= X$ or $S=X$". And since $U\neq \emptyset$, then the only possibility is $S=X$. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any nonempty open subset of an irreducible space is irreducible and dense.

$U\subset X$ is dense, and $(f-g)^{-1}(0)\supset U$ is closed, so $(f-g)^{-1}(0)=X\implies f=g$ on $X$.

It seems what you have written is also correct.